# spring security 5 prints trace Exception for oauth2 bad credentials

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

For Oauth2+jwt running on springboot, I've successfully implemented with spring4.

However, when I tried to upgrade it to spring5 (springboot2), whenever the user inputs the wrong account/password, the "Bad Credential" Exception was not caught by spring5. It will be printed with the traced exception to the log.

I've uploaded the code to github:  https://github.com/ShanGor/springboot-jwt

I've raised an issue to the project:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4933

```html
2017-12-29 10:06:13.168  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-29 10:06:13.917  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2017-12-29 10:06:13.917  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2017-12-29 10:06:13.918  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-12-29 10:06:13.918  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-12-29 10:06:13.919  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/check_token]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint.checkToken(java.lang.String)
2017-12-29 10:06:13.919  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-12-29 10:06:13.919  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelErrorEndpoint.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-29 10:06:13.922  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token_key],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenKeyEndpoint.getKey(java.security.Principal)
2017-12-29 10:06:14.425  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4c3c304c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@b0534cb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7ca9ea3e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6440ffc8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@7a7907db, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6c57abd9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@58d97e65, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@537b4e05, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3640cf55, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@48e05dfe, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@59b25dc3]
2017-12-29 10:06:14.436  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@488e38a4, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@23c39a0c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7cee62ba, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6c845ecf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4f048143, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@f13ab77, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3cfa8985, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7246caf3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@524a9adb, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@74292ac2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@45d0a092, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2c85c82e]
2017-12-29 10:06:14.438  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@35758726, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4a8bb2ae, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2b3471d8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@11e2fcb8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@6eb22e8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@79a9509b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@711b44c7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1e63d033, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5526a7e3, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3fc18a1e]
2017-12-29 10:06:14.439  WARN 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.a.web.builders.WebSecurity       : 

********************************************************************
**********        Security debugging is enabled.       *************
**********    This may include sensitive information.  *************
**********      Do not use in a production system!     *************
********************************************************************


2017-12-29 10:06:14.726  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2017-12-29 10:06:14.918  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7854ea4: startup date [Fri Dec 29 10:06:08 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-29 10:06:14.972  WARN 8152 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2017-12-29 10:06:14.997  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/springjwt/cities]}" onto public java.util.List<tech.comfortheart.oauth.jwt.model.domain.RandomCity> tech.comfortheart.oauth.jwt.controller.ResourceController.getUser()
2017-12-29 10:06:14.998  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/springjwt/users],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<tech.comfortheart.oauth.jwt.model.domain.User> tech.comfortheart.oauth.jwt.controller.ResourceController.getUsers()
2017-12-29 10:06:15.001  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-29 10:06:15.001  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-29 10:06:15.059  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-29 10:06:15.059  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-29 10:06:15.112  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-29 10:06:15.333  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-12-29 10:06:15.392  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-29 10:06:15.393  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-12-29 10:06:15.399  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2017-12-29 10:06:15.511  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2017-12-29 10:06:15.517  INFO 8152 --- [  restartedMain] t.c.oauth.jwt.SpringbootJwtApplication   : Started SpringbootJwtApplication in 7.375 seconds (JVM running for 9.298)
2017-12-29 10:06:20.580  INFO 8152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-29 10:06:20.580  INFO 8152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-12-29 10:06:20.620  INFO 8152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 40 ms
2017-12-29 10:06:20.628  INFO 8152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/oauth/token':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@191b82f2

servletPath:/oauth/token
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
authorization: Basic dGVzdGp3dGNsaWVudGlkOlhZN2ttem9OemwxMDA=
user-agent: curl/7.46.0
accept: */*
content-length: 55
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2017-12-29 10:06:20.684  INFO 8152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-12-29 10:06:20.818 ERROR 8152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Bad credentials

org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidGrantException: Bad credentials
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.getOAuth2Authentication(ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.getAccessToken(AbstractTokenGranter.java:70) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:65) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:38) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer$4.grant(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.java:561) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:132) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]

2017-12-29 10:06:20.893  WARN 8152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials"
```

Answer (score -1):

try add this to AuthorizationServerConfig ...if password is not encoded...otherwise use the correct password encoder...

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder =  NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    return encoder;
}
```